# How I can store and manage a db schema in Arango or Neo4j in Node.js project

Tags: node.js, neo4j, database-administration, arangodb, database-management

I can't understand how to manage a schema to have the same database structure for different environments(development, testing and production). And in deployment server.
How to define, store and update ArangoDB or Neo4j schema.

I know sequelize utility for SQL databases. It have tool for migrations between different schema versions (http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/migrations.html) to better understand what I want.

Answer (score 3):

There is an abstract migration framework https://github.com/tj/node-migrate

You can use it with any database because it allows you execute any code and save state to any place (by default to file)

Here is how I configured it for ArangoDB

```
npm i migrate --save-dev
```

add script to `package.json`

```
  "scripts": {
    "migrate": "migrate"
  },
```

create migrations folder

```
npm run migrate init
```

create migration

```
npm run migrate create test
```

replace migration implementation with

```
require('dotenv').config();
const arangojs = require('arangojs');

const db = new arangojs.Database({ url: process.env.DB_HOST });

db.useDatabase(process.env.DB_NAME);
db.useBasicAuth(process.env.DB_USERNAME, process.env.DB_PASSWORD);

module.exports.up = async (next) => {
  const collection = db.collection('test');
  await collection.create();
  next();
};

module.exports.down = async (next) => {
  const collection = db.collection('test');
  await collection.drop();
  next();
};
```

add to `.gitignore`

```
.migrate
```

run migration

```
npm run migrate up
```

rollback migration

```
npm run migrate down
```

Answer (score 2):

There are Schema evolution tools for ArangoDB, namely [migrantverde](https://github.com/deusdat/migrantverde) and its successor [arangoMigo](https://github.com/deusdat/arangomigo).

ArangoMigo uses Yaml files to describe schemata while Migrant verde used XML files.